# Error when test chaincode_example02.go in docker

Tags: docker, hyperledger

I just follow the **blockchain guide** (https://github.com/yeasy/blockchain_guide) to test hyperledger project example02 in the docker.

But when I type `peer chaincode deploy -p github.com/hyperledger/fabric/examples/chaincode/go/chaincode_example02 -c '{"Function":"init", "Args": ["a","100", "b", "200"]}'`, I get following error.

> Error: Non-empty JSON chaincode parameters must contain exactly 1 key: 'Args'

It's strange. I googled it but not found answer. Anyone can help me? Thank you.

Actually, when I use the pbft mode and type `docker-compose up`. I get the following error, but I ignored it. Is it the reason?

> vp2_1  | 04:27:04.945 [peer] handleChat -> ERRO 88e Error handling message: Peer FSM cannot handle message (DISC_GET_PEERS) with payload size (0) while in state: created
>
> vp2_1  | 04:27:04.953 [peer] handleChat -> ERRO 88f Error handling message: Peer FSM cannot handle message (DISC_GET_PEERS) with payload size (0) while in state: created
>
> vp2_1  | 04:27:06.845 [peer] ensureConnected -> WARN 890 Touch service indicates dropped connections, attempting to reconnect...
>
> vp2_1  | 04:27:09.945 [peer] handleChat -> ERRO 891 Error handling message: Peer FSM cannot handle message (DISC_GET_PEERS) with payload size (0) while in state: created
>
> vp2_1  | 04:27:09.952 [peer] handleChat -> ERRO 892 Error handling message: Peer FSM cannot handle message (DISC_GET_PEERS) with payload size (0) while in state: created
>
> vp2_1  | 04:27:12.845 [peer] ensureConnected -> WARN 893 Touch service indicates dropped connections, attempting to reconnect...
>
> vp2_1  | 04:27:14.946 [peer] handleChat -> ERRO 894 Error handling message: Peer FSM cannot handle message (DISC_GET_PEERS) with payload size (0) while in state: created

Comment: Now I just get the upper yellow block error, that is `Error: Non-empty JSON chaincode parameters must contain exactly 1 key: 'Args'`. I have solved `Peer FSM` error by open a new docker. Anyone can help me? It got me crazy these days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Format was changed. Parameter "Function" was moved to "Args" array. All parameters should be base64 encoded.
Old format:

`{"function":"init","args":["a", "1000", "b", "2000"]}}`

New format:

`{"args":['aW5pdA==', 'YQ==', 'MTAwMA==', 'Yg==', 'MjAwMA==']}`

**Updated**: Format was changed again. Base64 encoding is not necessary any longer. correct payload in latest (tested 08.31.2016) Fabric's version is:

`{“args”:['init', 'a', '100', 'b', '100']}`

Comment: peer chaincode query -C $CHANNEL -n $VZCHAINCODENAME -c '{"Args":["dosomethingfunction","parametervalue"]}'